# flash torch functionality not working through app-widget in nexus 5

Tags: android, flash, android-camera, google-nexus

Flash is turning-on fine from application (added surface_view to the layout), when I try to turn-on flash through app-widget it's not working. I used [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) and [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) Here is the code I am using

```
Camera mCamera;
SurfaceView preview;
mCamera = Camera.open();
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(preview.getCameraHolder());
Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
mCamera.setParameters(params);  
mCamera.startPreview();
```

Added permission and features in Manifest are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 8):

The camera needs a surface to cling to in order to open the
Flashlight..however SurfaceView cannot be applied to a        widget. So this is what you need to.....

Add this to your `turnFlashOn` code:

```
try {
mCamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also, remove all references to surfaceview in your code as it is not applicable in a widget

Comment: btw its mCamera.setPreviewTexture()

Comment: thanks @SuperStallion!! i've been looking all over for a solution.
i used setPreviewDisplay and coudlnt get the flashlight to work.